# Meteor(Blaze) : CFS: S3 Create thumbnail Image from Video and upload both to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, meteor

I am using CFS packages to upload videos to Amazon S3, but it takes a long time to load the videos on Amazon when they are of 10-20 MB. Till then, I want to use the videos' first frame and when clicked on play, the video should be streamed.